# Video Concatenating in FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to concatenate a couple of video files with ffmpeg for this i use

```
.././ffmpeg -i 01.mov -i op_IMG_20150221114715.mp4 -i 02.mov -i op_IMG_20150221114724.mp4 -i op_IMG_20150221114736.mp4 -strict -2 -filter_complex '[0:0] setsar=1/1[sarfix];[sarfix] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] [3:0] [3:1] [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

and it outputs this error

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built on Feb 16 2015 16:20:23 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads   --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '01.mov':
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:31:41
xmp             : 
  Duration: 00:00:02.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 558 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 480x480, 402 kb/s, SAR 480:480 DAR 1:1, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:31:41
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  encoder         : H.264
  timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 68 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:31:41
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:31:43
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'op_IMG_20150221114715.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
Duration: 00:00:04.07, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 539 kb/s
Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 427 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 11488 tbn, 59.83 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 120 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '02.mov':
Metadata:
   major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 537199360
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:32:12
xmp             : 
  Duration: 00:00:02.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 666 kb/s
Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 480x480, 445 kb/s, SAR 480:480 DAR 1:1, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:32:12
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  encoder         : H.264
  timecode        : 00:00:02:12
Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 119 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:32:12
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:00:02:12
Stream #2:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2015-02-13 11:32:15
  handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
  timecode        : 00:00:02:12

Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'op_IMG_20150221114724.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
Duration: 00:00:02.07, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 549 kb/s
Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 460 kb/s, 29.92 fps, 29.92 tbr, 11488 tbn, 59.83 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #3:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 111 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'op_IMG_20150221114736.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
Duration: 00:00:01.07, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 392 kb/s
Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x480    [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 334 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
Stream #4:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_concat_1 @ 0x7f922bc1cec0] Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 480x480, SAR 480:480) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (480x480, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_1 @ 0x7f922bc1cec0] Failed to configure output pad on   Parsed_concat_1
```

The issue seems like I need to apply sarfix on input files 02.mov also. But I dont know the syntax for that.

Comment: Please include the **complete** console output from your command. You left out some stuff.

Comment: implemented it using another library..however can u tell me the syntax to apply sarfix on input 02.mov also  in above command?

Comment: Looks like another drive-by-question. Did the answer provide an adequate solution?

Answer (score 1):

## Why some things must be set by the user

From the [concat filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

> All corresponding streams must have the same parameters in all
>   segments; the filtering system will automatically select a common
>   pixel format for video streams, and a common sample format, sample
>   rate and channel layout for audio streams, **but other settings, such as
>   resolution, must be converted explicitly by the user**.

More for the same docs:

> For this filter to work correctly, all segments must start at
>   timestamp 0.

All of your inputs share the same parameters except for SAR (*Sample* [aka *Pixel*] *Aspect Ratio*) and frame rate. It is also always good practice to set the timestamps of all inputs to 0 (even if they already are at 0 it won't hurt to do so).

## What you must do

1. Set timestamps to `0`. The [setpts filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) will be used.
2. Two inputs have a SAR of `480:480`, while the others has a SAR of `1:1`. I'm not sure why they are set as `480:480` instead of `1:1`. They all must either be `480:480` or `1:1`. You can try both and see what looks best. The [setsar filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setdar_002c-setsar) will be used.
3. Two inputs have a frame rate of `24`, one is `29.92`, and one is `30`. They all must have the same value, so the [fps filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) will be used.

## Filtergraph syntax

A **filtergraph** is your complete filtering command. A filtergraph consists of **filterchains**. Filterchains consist of groups of filters connected via commas. Filterchains are connected via semicolons. The inputs and outputs of filterchains and filtergraphs can be named so they can be referenced by other filters or filterchains.

### Basic filtergraph example

```
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]filter0,filter1,filter2[fc0]; \
 [1:v]filter3,filter4,filter5[fc1]; \
 [fc0][fc1]filter5[out]"
```

- `[0:v]` refers to the video from the first input file.
- `[fc0]` refers to the output from the first filterchain.

### Actual filtergraph example

```
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]fps=24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [2:v]setsar=1/1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [3:v]fps=24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; \
 [4:v]fps=24,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v4]; \
 [v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a][v3][3:a][v4][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
```